# Error: `redirect` can not be returned from getStaticProps during prerendering

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

In my Next.js application I am statically generating pages using `getStaticProps` like so

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  
  ...

  if (data.isRedirect) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: `${data.redirectTo}`,
        permanent: false,
      },
    };
  }
  return {
    props: {
      data,
    },
    revalidate: 10,
  };
}
```

It is working just as expected on localhost but when I deploy to Vercel i get this error.

> Error: `redirect` can not be returned from getStaticProps during
> prerendering

I don't understand this as Next.js has this example in their docs. https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation

Comment: If you check the docs closely you'll see it mentions this: "Note: Redirecting at build-time is currently not allowed and if the redirects are known at build-time they should be added in `next.config.js`.". I assume it's only possible to use `redirect` when using Incremental Static Regeneration, during a page regeneration - just not at build time.

Comment: Thanks @juliomalves. I don't know why they would give an example of how to do it in the docs and then have a note saying it is not allowed. I found a workaround using React instead.

Answer (score 5):

It is not currently possible to redirect from the server with Next.js static pages.

I hope they can make it happen some day, but until then the workaround is to load the page and then redirect client-side using the `useEffect` react hook.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const IndexPage = ({ data }) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (data?.home?.isRedirect) {
      router.push(data.home.redirectTo);
    }
  });
  return (
    <>
      {data && !data.isRedirect && (
      ...
```

Notice how I check for `!data.isRedirect`? This is to prevent the screen from flashing before the redirect.

Comment: Note that React will complain about conditionally rendering a `useEffect` - see [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). For a quick fix you can move the condition inside the `useEffect`.

Comment: Wow. You are right. I learn something new every day. The answer has been updated.

Comment: Also note that this is not a valid 307/308 redirect

Answer (score 3):

I found a workaround

I am using getStaticProps and also using dynamic revalidation but also using `fallback: 'blocking'` to manage my path which mean that my app will look at my headless CMS api to fetch non existant path/page at build time.

Since I am doing a check based on `process.env.npm_lifecycle_event` who can tell if you are building or running your app

```
if (process.env.npm_lifecycle_event === 'build')
  return {
    notFound: true
  }
return {
  redirect: {
    destination: '/404',
    permanent: false,
  },
}
```

Then if I am building my app I am returning notFound: true. Once I am running it will prefetch the path and then return my page to a my 404. I don't want it to be permanent since I am using dynamic revalidation.

With this check I can then avoid the following error

> Error: `redirect` can not be returned from getStaticProps during prerendering

Answer (score 1):

Initially i was also confused as i had the same issue where even if redirect syntax are allowed in getStaticProps, still then you give redirect items into GetStaticProps, it comes up with above exception

Actual issue is "Redirects are possible in GetStaticProps, but they are not possible during build and prerendering time" and that is why it is complaining that "it is not possible"

So just before GetStaticProps, GetStaticPaths is called, and it internally calls "sitemap-fetcher", in that you will need to customize the DefaultSitemap query so that it ignores those pages with redirect templates

What it will do is, it will ignore those pages from the array of pages which are fed to "GetStatiProps" and once you exclude those pages from being prerendered

you when you build and if those paths are excluded using your custom graphQL query, it will not complain about it

Let me know if you need detail code, i have it handy and can give it to you

Answer (score 0):

To use redirects you can use the redirects key in next.config.js:

next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/about',
        destination: '/',
        permanent: true,
      },
    ]
  },
}
```